# opencv python video rotation

Tags: python, opencv, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate the frame image from the live web camera but i am getting some one error , the same code is working fine when i use for any saved image  in system but it is not working fine with the web cam, if somebody can help me thanx in advance

```
import cv2.cv as cv

import cv2

import numpy as np

def trackcall(angle):

        image0 = rotateImage(image, angle)
        cv.ShowImage("imageRotation",image0);


def rotateImage(image, angle):

    image0 = image
    if hasattr(image, 'shape'):
        image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape)/2)
        shape = tuple(image.shape)
    elif hasattr(image, 'width') and hasattr(image, 'height'):
        image_center = tuple(np.array((image.width/2, image.height/2)))
        shape = (image.width, image.height)
    else: 
        raise Exception, 'Unable to acquire dimensions of image for type %s.' % (type(image),)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle,1.0)
    image = np.asarray( image[:,:] )

    rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, shape, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    # Copy the rotated data back into the original image object.
    cv.SetData(image0, rotated_image.tostring())

    return image0

angle = 720

vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv.NamedWindow('imageRotation',cv.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.NamedWindow('imageMeter',cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv.CreateTrackbar("rotate","imageMeter",360,angle,trackcall)
#image = cv.LoadImage('C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
#image0 = rotateImage(image, angle)
if vc.isOpened():

        rval = True, image = vc.read()
else:
        rval = False

while rval:

        image = vc.read()
        trackcall(0)


key = cv.WaitKey(0)
if key == 27:

    cv.DestroyWindow('imageRotation')
    cv.DestroyWindow("imageMeter")
```

Errors in the program are

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\VideoRotation\imageRotationWithTrackbar.py", line 44, in 
    trackcall(0)

File "D:\VideoRotation\imageRotationWithTrackbar.py", line 6, in trackcall
    image0 = rotateImage(image, angle)

File "D:\VideoRotation\imageRotationWithTrackbar.py", line 19, in rotateImage
    raise Exception, 'Unable to acquire dimensions of image for type %s.' % (type(image),)

Exception: Unable to acquire dimensions of image for type .

Answer (score 2):

To ignore rotation in image while camera rotating you can use this code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture (0)

width = 400
height = 350

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))
    flipped = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    framerot = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
    framerot = cv2.resize(framerot, (width, height))
    StackImg = np.hstack([frame, flipped, framerot])
    cv2.imshow("ImageStacked", StackImg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading the webcam's feed correctly.  `vc.read()` returns two values, `retval` and `image`.  See [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.VideoCapture.read).

Your problem is you are reading both into a single value, namely, `image`, and that is why your image seems to be represented as a tuple.

So `image = vc.read()` should become `retval, image = vc.read()`

However, I think there might be something else wrong in your code in your use of `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle,1.0)`... I will look a little later if I can see what's wrong.

Comment: yes you are right it is giving the error in the function cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0) that function takes exactly 2 arguments ( 3 given) but in the document it is having 3 arguments http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

Comment: i fixed the tuple problem. but i am not able to fix rotation function problem. cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle,1.0). does any other function is there by which i can do the same work as i was trying with cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(...) function

Comment: You should probably ask that as a new question, that will likely get you more responses. Close off this question, and maybe someone can help you with the new one. My thesis needs to be handed in next week so unfortunately I cannot help you right now, but if you read the documentation and explain in your new question exactly what you want to do I am sure someone will be able to help you.  I will also look at it once I have some time available again!